# Different nuance between "on + (Object)'s order" , "by + (Object)'s order"

Tags: word-choice

I'm taking this money on my uncle's order.

I'm taking this money by my uncle's order.

What is the difference between those two sentences above, and which one would a native English speaker use or widely use?

Comment: to be honest I don't think we'd use either. maybe "on account of" or "because my uncle ordered me to."

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is a difference.   "On my uncle's order" means "because my uncle told me so".  "By my uncle's order" means "my uncle's order empowers me/gives me the right to"

Answer (score 1):

You do something **by** someone's order, so it should be:

> I'm taking this money by my uncle's order.

To have different nuances you would need to use a different verb. Other ways of saying it from the less pressing to the more pressing.

- at his wish
- at his instruction
- at his bidding, at his command, at his demand (they seem pretty equal to me but someone please rectify if I'm wrong)
- at his behest